# find out if the server root password is known with php or a bash-script

Tags: php, bash, security

Is there a way to find out if the shell Ubuntu root password is a certain word?

I deliver an **image** with a full Ubuntu installation to my customers, that has a certain root password.

I would like to add a check if the server is secure now, so I would like to try out the known standard password and if it is still the standard it should give out a warning that the rootpassword must be changed.

***I don't want to brute force the server***, I already know the standard-password and just want to check, if the new admin has changed the standard root-password, that was set in the **Image** that was used to copy the server.

I thought of something like

```
exec('ssh root@localhost --password=my_known_standard_pass')
```

Or maybe I could somehow create a shell script, that logs in with the sshkey stored somewhere that tries out the login and returns the success or not.

Comment: So you're asking how to brute-force a root shell via PHP?

Comment: You should enforce using secure passwords using administrative methods

Comment: I clarified my question: I cannot force a change cause the server is a direct copy of another image

Comment: Answer his question if you know how - if he wants to brute-force his own server, so be it!

Comment: Though your intentions are not for bad, this is exactly the type of program hackers are looking for. It's executing shell commands -and one little mistake -and BAM I've got root access to the machine. I'm just saying, you really need to be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're distributing an image, you know not only the root password, but also its encryption. You could implement a check in some startup file whether the encrypted password is still the original one.

Comment: ok, where do I find the encrypted password?

Comment: probably in /etc/shadow

Comment: essentially, something like `if grep -q '^root:eSdvXa\$oq\.Wzzxw1:' /etc/shadow ; then ...` should be sufficient. Remember to escape grep metacharacters. (untested)

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a script that is run on the 1st login and forces a password change.